# How to determine direction of induced current in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

A current-carrying wire has a ring around it, the current steadily decreases, what is the direction of induced current in the ring?

My attempt- net flux through loop is always zero, so induced current doesn't exist.

What's your approach?

[image]

Comment: And you understand $why$ the flux through the loop is always zero?

Comment: Can you please explain it me, or just confirm that it is true  that flux is zero? @philipWood

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, the flux through the loop is zero, so induced current doesn't exist.

Reason : The wire carrying current produces magnetic field perpendicular to the wire and parallel to the plane of loop. Due to this, there are no magnetic field lines passing through the loop hence making the flux zero due to which no induced current exists.